# How to auto submitting in require sign-in google form from google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I have apps script for auto submit in google form. It work until the Form change method to require sign-in. So my script do not work. How can apps script support sign-in or have any way to solve this.

Thank you for any answer

```
function doGet() {
    var httpStatus = response.getResponseCode();
    Logger.log( httpStatus );
}
```

Comment: I thought that in your question when you provide your current script of `I have apps script for auto submit in google form.`, it might help users think of the solution.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, Thank for you advice. Now I add my code. Please advice.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I cannot understand `It work until the Form change method to require sign-in.`. Can I ask you about the detail of it? And, can you provide the detail of `So my script do not work.`?

Comment: @Tanaike , I'm not Form owner, I'm just user. I used to the script everyday because the form is not require sigin-in. but now it require. So it make my script don't work. when I exeucute the script the httpstatus will return code 400, then I try copy "myLink"  url and paste in browser it show popup "Submit response?" confirmation again. Sorry for my english I'm not native.

Comment: Can you share more details on how the form is created and the process you follow? I have tried your code on a Form I have been invited to and on the script the `httpStatus` returns 200

Comment: @Kessy ,Hi Thanks for comment, I don't knows how form create I just have link. This is The Form that require Sign-in, You can try fill in and submit via browser or with google apps script.  https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSccr4T6N1p8jLLm2kilfBWs9FtvKywlaLbY_MysQvoaT-qdEQ/viewform

Comment: Hi, is this the full code you used to answer the form with? If not, can you share it and if possible share the details of how is used to work with the non Sign-in required form?

Answer (score 0):

The form setting has been changed to sign-in required. But it seems no any payload of login data or cookie be set in fetch function.

Why not use the [Form Service of Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms) ? I created a new form with sign-in required and submitted through the Google Apps Script. It works fine.

```
function submit(formID) {
  const form = FormApp.openById(formID);
  let formResponse = form.createResponse();
  formResponse.submit(); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I'm not an owner's Form. I'm just user. The script I used for long time to submit everyday. So Can you have an example if you are not Form owner?